# Click cell to generate dynamic table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-tables

I'm working in a table with Excel. Here is an example of the sheet, this is save in Sheet1:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| al | id | id | id |
| df | id | desc | desc |
| df | id | id | desc |
| df | id | id | id |
| ff | desc | id | desc |
| ff | desc | id | desc |
| al | id | id | id |
| al | id | id | desc |
| mn | desc | desc | desc |
| mn | desc | desc | desc |
| ff | desc | id | desc |

In this table, the goal was to compare the column A with duplicate values and you will get a table of columns A B C and D. With that table, I have to compare de columns B C and D at once. Later, I have to create a new column where I have to put 1 if they all match, 0 otherwise. For the previous table, this is what I get:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| al | 0 |
| df | 0 |
| ff | 1 |
| mn | 1 |

I save this new table in other sheet named Sheet2. There are hundreds of rows in the table.

Now, I want to click in a cell of A and generate like dynamic table in the columns, for instance D,E,F,G; and get just the information in relation with the value of the cell A.

I put an example:

If I click in the value cell A2, in the columns from D to G, the following information has to be generated:

| D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| al | id | id | id |
| al | id | id | id |
| al | id | id | desc |

If I click in the cell A4, this is what I have to get

| D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ff | desc | id | desc |
| ff | desc | id | desc |
| ff | desc | id | desc |

So, how can I do that?

Is there an option that do all this or I have to code a formula?

Comment: So what is the question here? Where did you get stuck coding/trying? What do you need help with?

Comment: @JvdV sorry, I forget to put this. I already edited with the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following:

[image]

Formula in `F1` (as per my answer to your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75929037/9758194) question):

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(A1:A11),HSTACK(x,--MAP(x,LAMBDA(y,ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(B1:D11,A1:A11=y)))=1))))
```

Formula in `F6`:

```
=FILTER(A1:D11,A1:A11=INDIRECT(CELL("address")),"")
```

This is a volatile function which means that when you select a cell in range `F1:F4` and hit <kbd>F9</kbd> you'd recalculate these functions meaning the spilled result will change accordingly.

It's not the same as changing the table upon a simple click, but that would require VBA. For example, use the following simplified code in your sheet's code panel:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F1:F4")) Is Nothing And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    Range("F6").Formula2 = "=FILTER(A1:D11,A1:A11=""" & Target.Value2 & ""","""")"
End If

End Sub
```

[image]