# Generate a table with condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on a table with Excel. Here is an example of my table in Sheet1:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| al | id | id | id |
| df | id | desc | desc |
| df | id | id | desc |
| df | id | id | id |
| ff | desc | id | desc |
| ff | desc | id | desc |
| al | id | id | id |
| al | id | id | desc |
| mn | desc | desc | desc |
| mn | desc | desc | desc |
| ff | desc | id | desc |

In this table, the goal was to compare column A with duplicate values and you will get a table of columns A B C, and D. With that table, I have to compare de columns B C and D at once. Later, I have to create a new column where I have to put 1 if they all match, and 0 otherwise. For the previous table, this is what I get:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| al | 0 |
| df | 0 |
| ff | 1 |
| mn | 1 |

This is saved in another sheet called Sheet2.

Now, I want to save in another Sheet, called Sheet3, all the information of Sheet1 where in Sheet2 there is a 0. For example, in Sheet3 there should be:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| al | id | id | id |
| al | id | id | id |
| al | id | id | desc |
| df | id | desc | desc |
| df | id | id | desc |
| df | id | id | id |

How it looks, I want all of the values for column A in Sheet1, together by rows in Sheet3.

How can I do that?

Best regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per below screenshot I have used the following formulas.

<kbd>G1</kbd> cell formula-

```
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(A1:A11),
BYROW(UNIQUE(A1:A11),
LAMBDA(x,IF(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$1:$D$11,$A$1:$A$11=x)))>1,0,1))))
```

<kbd>J1</kbd> cell formula.

```
=LET(x,FILTER(UNIQUE(A1:A11),BYROW(UNIQUE(A1:A11),LAMBDA(x,IF(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$1:$D$11,$A$1:$A$11=x)))>1,0,1)))=0),
y,REDUCE("",x,LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,FILTER(A1:D11,A1:A11=b)))),DROP(y,1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Again, as per previous answers to your questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75941391/9758194) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75929037/9758194), I used the following formula to generate your initial table:

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(A1:A11),HSTACK(x,--MAP(x,LAMBDA(y,ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(B1:D11,A1:A11=y)))=1))))
```

To generate your desired output in a 2nd table just simple use:

[image]

Formula in `F6`:

```
=SORT(FILTER(A1:D11,NOT(VLOOKUP(A1:A11,F1#,2,0))))
```

Comment: your code is not working for me. The problem is the function ````--MAP````; I do no know why is not working.

Comment: Instead of 'MAP()' try 'BYROW()'. It would have the same effect. Some locales have a problem with the MAP function (the Dutch version of Excel for example.). I for example switched to the English version and since have no problem with this function. @DatBigD